# How can I use `amod` on MATLAB R2012b?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use `amod` on  MATLAB R2012b but it seems it is no longer included in recent versions, what is its replacement?

Comment: Looks like amod is from the communications toolbox.

Comment: but has been renamed ammod.

Answer (score 1):

On R2010a:

```
>> help amod
 AMOD 

 WARNING: This is an obsolete function and may be removed in the future.
          Please use AMMOD, FMMOD, PMMOD or SSBMOD instead.
```